# Redis high availability - increment sync if master node fails

Tags: redis, failover

How to handle this situation.

1) there is a setup of 1 Master (M) and 2 Slaves (S)

2) you perform an increment of a value (and then you use it as a unique identifier)

3) it increments on Master, but fails to sync to Slaves (i.e. network lag or issue)

4) Master dies same time

5) New Master has been elected

6) No nodes from the cluster knows about the increment and with next inc it will bring next value, that is a duplicate.

Maybe Redis is not best solution to have a high-speed increment key-value store. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the worker would need to call [`WAIT`](https://redis.io/commands/wait) after incrementing to ensure that the change is synchronized.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, thank you very much for the tip. Main question here is to find a solution without performance degradation. Do you have experience with that, how performance is affected implementing WAIT?

Comment: The performance cost is usually just another request to Redis from the WAITing client - in most cases this would be negligible but you should test it with your code.